# Regex Beginning to End of a text file

Tags: c#, regex, xml

Hi I would like to read only text including `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` to `</Document>` from a large text files. 
You can say it will need text **START WITH** `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` and **END** with `</Document>`. Mean separate XML Part from the document. Could you please help me to provide Regex in C#

Currently I am using following code :

```
if (text.Contains("<?xml"))
{
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"(?s)<?xml(.*?)</Document>"))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

However it is now not including .?xml... and ./Document.

Please advice

Comment: The obvious question: why don't you use an XML parser instead?

Comment: You don't need to use regex, use text.IndexOf or an xml parser

Comment: From the regex tag: " NOTE: Asking for HTML, JSON, etc. regexes tends to be met with negative reactions. If there is a parser for it, use that instead."

Comment: Sorry I can not use "XML parser " because this xml part I am extracting from an email. Where its contains Body, CC, Subject and lots of other junk. I need only XML part from the Email Body.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the characters in your Regex are not escaped and you can use match group 0 to include the entire matched string. I've updated your example below:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"(?s)\<\?xml(.*)</Document>"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```